# Error on statement.executeUpdate();

Tags: java, jdbc

```
import java.sql.*;

public class Query1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://demo.c25xakasledb.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3307/demo";
        String user = "zzzzz";
        String password = "xxxxx";

        try {
            // 1. Get a connection to the database
            Connection connection = DriverManager
                    .getConnection(
                            "jdbc:mysql://demo.c25xakasledb.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3307/demo",
                            "zzzz", "xxxxx");

            // 2. Create statement
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

            // 3. Execute a sql query
            // ResultSet
            // resultset=statement.executeQuery("select * from PERSON");
            String sql = "insert into PERSON"
                    + "(FName, Minit, LName, SSN, B_date, Address, County, Sex, Phone,Type_id,Username,Password, Email)"
                    + "values"
                    + "('Ellen','G','White','115-77-1375','1897-03-31','107 First Street grafton nd 58216',"
                    + "'Polk', 'F','(347)234-3513',3,'',egwhite','egwhite@yahoo.com')";
            statement.executeUpdate(sql);
            System.out.println("Insert complete");

            /*
             * //4. Process result while(resultset.next()){
             * System.out.println(resultset
             * .getString("FName")+","+resultset.getString("LName")+
             * ","+resultset
             * .getString("SSN")+","+resultset.getString("B_date")+","+
             * resultset
             * .getString("County")+","+resultset.getString("Sex")+","+resultset
             * .getString("Phone")); }
             */

        } catch (SQLException sqlException) {

            sqlException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you forget username in the sql query? or password?

Comment: Please post error log.

Comment: at Query1.main(Query1.java:27)

Comment: please provide the error log, if you really need solution

Comment: Please post the exception stacktrace